# Is it possible to attach usb to an instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to attach usb to an instance? Just curious to know if it is possible to attach memory stick or external hard disk on GCP instance

Comment: This may be possible. There are third-party products that can connect USB devices over TCP/IP. However, I have never tried them in the cloud, only in datacenters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not possible to attach USB (or any other storage device that you own) to a GCP VM instance.**

Only [supported storage solutions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks) are described in the official documentation.

It's possible to attach a local SSD disk but it's just a temporary storage - in case of VM restart (or shutdown) data are lost (in most cases).

You could mount your own USB stick as a samba share but you'd have to run another machine somewhere where you can physically connect it and share it from.